# How do I write comments in a SpecFlow Feature?

Tags: specflow

I'd like to include some comments in a SpecFlow feature.

I get the the following error:

```
Custom tool error: Parsing error near '/*'
```

I've tried the following:

```
// comment
/* comment */
-- comment
' comment
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The answer is #comment. duh.

Comment: answered your own question there then.

Comment: yes. and no. i don't have enough rep yet to answer my own question. i could only add comment with answer! :)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As stated by sarfest above - its simply `#`-sign for comments.

There are no multiline comments but that's easily solved if you can do a vertical selection (hold down ALT-key and select in Visual Studio). 
Vertical select and the enter a #-sign.

**Additional information:** the line has to **start** with a #, and optionally any whitespace. This means you cannot combine comments with actual code on the same line.

Comment: When testing using the feature language, my goal is to define a feature language that is - as far as possible - self descriptive. With that in mind, there should only be less need for additional comments. Don't get me wrong, I use comments in the feature files myself, however, if I find myself writing a multiline comment in the feature, I ask myself: "How can I improve my feature language in order to avoid such comments?"

Answer (score 8):

also, if you want to perform multiline comments in an easy way (on visual studio),

you can select the lines to be commented, and hit CTRL+K+C to comment, CTRL+K+U to Uncomment.

Comment: This does work in SpecFlow feature files now for anyone who comes across this question now.

Comment: As of today this WORKS in SpecFlow feature files. The comment above is no longer true

Answer (score 2):

thank you for the wonderful idea. I just need to press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and select the entire lines (just the little space which holds only one character space in each line) and then enter # which result
from
xyz
abc
to

## '# xyz'

## '# abc'

Answer (score 0):

You can add comment lines to the feature files at any place starting the line with the # sign. Be careful however, as comments in the specification are often signs of wrongly specified acceptance criteria.

The comment lines are ignored by SpecFlow.